# get character from r to java use rcaller

Tags: java, r, rcaller

The results in R is character or describe.I want to get the resule from R then into Java.I use RCaller.

I use the code below is not works.

```
    code.clear();

    code.addRCode("c1<-factor(describe(1:10)$counts)");
    code.addRCode("c2<-as.numeric(as.character(c1))");

    System.out.println(code.toString());

    caller.setRCode(code);
    caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("c2");


    // String[] cc = caller.getParser().getAsStringArray("de");
    double[] cc = caller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("c2");
    System.out.println(caller.getParser().getClass());


    for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(cc[i]);
    }
}
```

But I use these below is working!

```
            code.clear();
    code.addRCode("c1<-factor(3.3:9.3)");
    code.addRCode("c2<-as.numeric(as.character(c1))");

    System.out.println(code.toString());

    caller.setRCode(code);
    caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("c2");


    // String[] cc = caller.getParser().getAsStringArray("de");
    double[] cc = caller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("c2");
    System.out.println(caller.getParser().getClass());


    for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(cc[i]);
    }
}
```

why?
If I want get character or other type data from R to Java use RCaller,what can I do?Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't understand why are you asking such long question. The 2 parts are mostly the same ( only the first statement is different). Maybe you should add something like `code.addRCode("library(Hmisc)");`

Comment: What is the error message that you get with the upper code? What is in 'describe(1:10)$counts' in your R, are you sure it is loaded when using RCaller and accessible? Notice that your R script session is most likely a fresh one when called with RCaller. Perhaps you need to load the workspace inside the R script before this portion with e.g. code.addRCode implementing a load-command.

Answer (score 0):

because you use getAsDoubleArray() which returns an array of double data type.